# Reading and displaying openCV IplImage

Tags: c, opencv

On the client side, I create IplImage using openCV and send it as binary data through TCP socket.

```
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(480, 360), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
```

After I receive the data on the server, how do it read it and display it?

```
IplImage *img = ???
cvNamedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("image", img);
cvWaitKey();
cvDestroyWindow("image");
```

Comment: Note: this is ancient OpenCV *v1* API (before the API was changed to C++). it stopped being available many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Send the size, depth, and nChannels of the image through the socket, too. You can create your image server-side, and use memcpy() or just set the pointer of your img to the pointer to the received binary data.

Comment: I only send the size as I already know the depth(8U) and nChannels(4). how do I reconstruct the image?

Comment: Why don't you try the following: typecast the binary data you have obtained on the server to an IplImage* and see if you can display it.

Comment: i have tried that but it didn't show up. the socket should be ok as I can send, receive and display other image formats.

Comment: Does the size of the data you received actually correspond to the IplImage's size? Do you get around 173kb?

Comment: most of the time i received 691.2kb, sometimes it varies. how do you know it's 173kb?